# Hide HTML content by hovering over some SVG element

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to hide and unhide some html paragraph tag

when hovering over a component in SVG.

SVG (graphic.svg):

```
<svg height="300" width="300">
  <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/> 
  <circle class="redcircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="purple" />
</svg>
```

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
     <embed src="graphic.svg" />
     <p class="item"> this is a hidden text, should only appear when hover over red circle</p> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS (styles.css):

```
.item {
   display:none;
}
.redcircle:hover .item{
   display:block;
}
```

The paragraph in the html is hidden so CSS is working fine. also the hover in SVG is working on its own but it is not making the paragraph visible in html.
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: you've two separate documents, the embed and the container. CSS does not apply cross-document. inline SVG is your best bet if you want to do this, that way there's only one document.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/2b6ya9nj/43/ as svg is not part of html doc, i used as inline and gave class to it

Comment: Even with inlined svg – You can't solve this with css alone. Your .item element is neither a child `.redcircle:hover .item` nor an adjacent silbing `.redcircle:hover + .item`. You would need to traverse the DOM: first goto your parentNode (svg) then select the nextElementSibling (.item). So you need some javaScript since css doesn't have a parentSelector. You might put your item inside the svg by svgs native `<text>`. However, this element type is pretty "quirky": you don't have the same styling options like in html .